# Qt C++: How to store function pointer in map when function have different parameter type

Tags: c++, qt, function, pointers, dictionary

I'm try to implement kind of [self description Entity] like this

```
//entity.h
class Entity : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(long Id READ Id WRITE setId NOTIFY IdChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString Text READ Text WRITE setText NOTIFY TextChanged)

private:
    long _id;
    QString _text;

    typedef void (Entity::*LongFnPtr)(long);
    std::map<std::string, LongFnPtr> longSetter;

    typedef void (Entity::*StringFnPtr)(QString);
    std::map<std::string, StringFnPtr> stringSetter;

public:

    Entity();

    void SetValue(std::string propName, long value);
    void SetValue(std::string propName, QString value);

    //Id Property
    long Id();
    void setId(long id);

    //Text Property
    QString Text();
    void setText(QString text);
}
```

And

```
//entity.cpp
Entity::Entity()
{
    this->longSetter["Id"] = &Entity::setId;
    this->stringSetter["Text"] = &Entity::setText;

}

long Entity::Id(){
    return _id;
}

void Entity::setId(long id){
    _id = id;
}

QString Entity::Text(){
    return _text;
}

void Entity::setText(QString text){
    _text = text;
}

void Entity:SetValue(std::string propName, long value){
    if (longSetter[propName]){
        (this->*longSetter[propName](value)
    }
}

void Entity:SetValue(std::string propName, QString value){
    if (stringSetter[propName]){
        (this->*stringSetter[propName](value)
    }
}
```

My 2 questions is:

1. How to create 1 function pointer & propSetter map for all different data type
2. I know that the function pointer signatural is specific for Entity class. How can I use this Entity class as Base class and reuse those SetValue function for derived class's properties setter?

Comment: It looks like you are recoding the Qt Property system without really an explanation why you want to do that, since it is already in place, is there perhaps a reason why the Qt Property system does not work for you?
The Docs are quite good on the [Qt Property System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html), pay attention to [Reading an Writing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html#reading-and-writing-properties-with-the-meta-object-system) properties

Comment: You save my life... such a noob question... ! :D I'm just start learn Qt for few days and trying to build ORM for my project. doesn't know this Property System exist ! Many Thanks & Respect !!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for [The Badger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/991000/the-badger) !!!

Never thought it already exist.

Just use setProperty function

```
Enity *obj = new Entity();
obj->setProperty("Id", 1);
obj->setProperty("Text", "Some text");
```

feeling to stupid !!!